# Qt как делать проверку на авторизацию

Tags: qt

Пишу десктопное приложение (`crm`).

База лежит в интернете. Все логины и пароли там же. Как правильнее сделать чтобы при работе с приложением было в нем видно других пользователей, которыe с ней работают?

Если при авторизации в программу ставить `true` в соответствующую ячейку базы, а при выходе ставить `false`. Потом через `QTimer` считывать `SELECT` всех кто = `true` и выводить списком?
Как обычно делают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно не оставляют сервер баз данных доступным в Интернете напрямую. Обычно присутствует какой-либо сервис (служба/демон), пусть даже и занимающийся только тем, что ретрансляцией запросов от клиентов к СУБД. Это вопрос безопасности, и если в вашей ситуации иное, то имеет смысл над ним задуматься.

Список тех, кто в онлайне (да и любую иную информацию) можно получать не только при помощи периодического опроса серверной части, но и при помощи подписки на уведомление. Разумеется, что второе должно поддерживаться сервером. СУБД такого механизма обычно не предоставляют, но им может оказаться тот самый серверный фронтэнд, о котором говорилось в первом абзаце настоящего ответа. В этом случае клиент может оформить так называемую подписку на уведомления о некоем событии, а уже сервер будет отсылать информацию об изменениях по факту их наступления.

Конечно, СУБД не будет предупреждать об изменениях и саму серверную часть, но то, что кто-то авторизовался или разлогинился, - эти события так или иначе всё равно пойдут в виде запросов от клиентов к серверу, а значит база данных здесь вовсе не является принципиально необходимым элементом. Максимум, что ей обычно дают сохранять - это долговременно живущие ключи, описывающие сессию, тогда как проверку факта онлайна или отсутствия подключения с клиентами серверная часть может вполне себе отработать самостоятельно, просто напросто опросив имеющиеся на учёте сокеты.

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать отдельную таблицу открытых сессий (айди сессии, айди пользователя, время отрытия, время закрытия, ...) (при открытии создается запись, при закрытии сессии ставится дата закрытия в одно из полей). Преимущество в том, что ведется история сессий. Делать запросы селектом на непустые поля даты закрытия (или можно и явный признак закрытия - истина/ложь)

P.S. Закрытие на стороне сервера происходит явно при закрытии программы/высылки команды, либо при длительном отстутсвиии ответа от клиента